# I can't get my JavaScript eventlistener to work properly

Tags: javascript, scope, greasemonkey, closures, event-listener

This has got me stumped, I've tried lots of different things, but I can't get this to work.
Can anyone help? No matter what I try I can't get the click eventlistener on the link to fire. The code is in a greasemonkey script. I believe I have to use the closure method to be able to refer to the function dropit in the greasemonkey script, as it is not available to the code on the page.

```
dropit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.textContent);
}

document.getElementById('newlink').addEventListener('click',
         function (e){
                   return function (){
                     dropit(e);
                   }
                 }(),false);
```

Comment: What's wrong with document.getElementById('newlink').addEventListener('click', dropit, false );

Comment: because the dropit function is code in a greasemonkey script, and at the time of the click event, the greasemonkey code will not be accessible by the page elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have your Greasemonkey script *write* the code into a new `<script>` tag in the page. Once that's done, then your in-page event handler setup can proceed as normally. At least, that's the only way I've ever known to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`e` must be passed into second function inside addEventListener, not first.
Like this:

```
dropit = function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(e.target.textContent);
}

document.getElementById('newlink').addEventListener('click',
         function (e){
                   return function (e){
                     dropit(e);
                   }
                 }(e),false);
```

Comment: i tried this and it doesnt work unfortunately :(

when it tries to add the eventlistener, i get the error "e is not defined"

Comment: That's because this answer is just wrong, and even if it weren't wrong it wouldn't work anyway.  The "dropit" function is never going to be visible if it's defined in your Greasemonkey code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='mylink' href='http://www.google.com'>google</a> the link 

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.0.0/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
YUI().use('event', function(Y){

  Y.one('#mylink').on('click', function(e){
    e.halt();
    alert(this.get('href'));  
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: i dont want to use YUI though

Answer (score 0):

here is the non YUI version

```
<a id='mylink' href='#'>google</a> the link 

<script>

(function(){
  var dropit = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.target.textContent);
  }

  document.getElementById('mylink').addEventListener('click', dropit, false);
}());
</script>
```